# SQL Server BETWEEN and OR Statement usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, between

I'm trying to use Between and OR clause in same SQL statement in SQL Server and every time I'm getting empty result, anyone have an idea about this ? My original SQL is formed like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM opportunity AS oppt
WHERE oppt.Location='O/S' 
   OR oppt.Location='Overseas' 
  AND oppt.OPEN_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         AND '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: What is the data type of `oppt.OPEN_DATE`?

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: Try and use brackets for the two parts with `OR`: `WHERE (oppt.Location='O/S' 
   OR oppt.Location='Overseas')
  AND oppt.OPEN_DATE `...

Comment: Be aware that your where clause says that, if `Location` equals `O/S`, nothing else matters - this may not be what you want, so after fixing the original issue, you may also need to introduce appropriate parentheses.

Comment: In addition to other comments about putting the smaller value first, be careful using `BETWEEN` with `datetime` values: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @RBarryYoung's answer, I'd also recommend putting brackets around your conditions. This makes it explicit, what you intend to be the outcome/how the conditions should be applied.

i.e.

```
WHERE (oppt.Location='O/S' 
   OR oppt.Location='Overseas')
  AND oppt.OPEN_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         AND '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

is different to:

```
WHERE oppt.Location='O/S' 
   OR (oppt.Location='Overseas'
  AND oppt.OPEN_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         AND '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

It's the 2nd of the above that is what you currently have, whereas you probably mean the first.

Read up on [Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) - this tells you in which order, various operators are executed in. In this case `AND` is applied before `OR`. But using brackets appropriately to group your conditions helps remove the risk operator precedence having unintended consequences.

I suspect in your case, you are wanting the first of my above examples, which actually you can rationalise down to:

```
WHERE oppt.Location IN ('O/S', 'Overseas')
      AND oppt.OPEN_DATE BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                             AND '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Thanks Ada second solution worked your last suggestion worked perfectly.. cheers

Answer (score 5):

The BETWEEN predicate requires that the *lower* value be first and the *higher* value second, or else you'll get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use () for queries and correct dates in between statement (lower then higher),

In your case it will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM opportunity AS oppt
WHERE (oppt.Location='O/S' OR oppt.Location='Overseas')
    AND oppt.OPEN_DATE BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
```